# break in running program in python

Tags: python, terminal, runtime-error, break, autopep8

when i run this code in terminal** i should prees" enter " key to run after line 6 **
i dont know the problem
i'm in the learning python proccess
thank all of you in advance........

```
print("hi dear,\n welcom to my program in python")
name = input("please enter your name:")


def greeting(name):
    print(input(f"hello dear {name}"))


greeting(name)
question1 = print(input(f"how are you today dear {name}?"))
answer1 = "fine"
if answer1 == True:
    print("good to know that\nGood Luck my Friend")
else:
    print(input(q2="describe for me what happen to you??!!"))
    q2 = ""
    if q2 == True:
        print("ok,no problem...we can solve it.\nplease call to your best friend or doctor for get better.")
else:
    print("contact me on this account\nMisagh.babolsar@gmail.com!!!")
```

Comment: What do you expect `print(input(...))` to do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I am not sure what you mean by press enter as it doesn't seem that any of your prompts expect enter specifically. Anyway the problem is input doesn't take any arguments. Meaning input(q2="enter a value") is not vaild. It should be q2=inpt("enter a value"). And that leads us to one more problem. Here `question1 = print(input(f"how are you today dear {name}?"))` you are not saving the value returned from the user in `question1`, but using it in print and the return value from print is stored in `question1` which is `None`. Try this line alone and print `question1` to see what I mean. Now I believe there is still some logical error in your code because you write `q2=""` after the input so in this case the input will never be stored because you overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
print("hi dear,\n welcom to my program in python")
name = input("please enter your name:")

def greeting(name):
    print(f"hello dear {name}")

greeting(name)
question1 = input(f"how are you today dear {name}? ")
answer1 = "fine"
if question1 = answer1:
    print("good to know that\nGood Luck my Friend")
else:
    q2 = input("describe for me what happened to you??!! ")
    if q2 == True:
        print("ok, no problem...we can solve it.\nplease call your best friend or doctor to get better.")
    else:
        print("contact me on this account\nMisagh.babolsar@gmail.com!!!")
```

When asking for input, the print keyword is not required. And you have to check if the user has entered "fine" in line 10. Hope this helps.